# Creating Alice's Private Key in Java (power & modulus)

Tags: java, diffie-hellman

I have embarked on an assignment and I can't seem to solve it. The answer should be 21 for Alice Public Key but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried using `double` but the answer was the same (426).

```
public class DiffieHellman {
// Main method to call
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Shared values
    int p = 941;
    int g = 627;
    alicePrivateKey(p, g);
    bobPrivateKey(p, g);
}

// Generate alice key
private static void alicePrivateKey(int p, int g) {
    int alicePrivateKey = 12;
    System.out.println("Prime: " + p);
    System.out.println("Base: " + g);
    System.out.println("Alice Private Key: " + alicePrivateKey);
    System.out.println("Alice Public Key: " + Math.pow(g, alicePrivateKey) % p);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Prime: 941

Base: 627

Alice Private Key: 12

Alice Public Key: 426.0
```

How do I get the Alice Public Key to be `21`? Can somebody enlighten me on this one?

Answer (score 2):

`Math.pow` is ill-suited for such large numbers, I suggest you use `BigIntegers` for such calculations.

```
private static void alicePrivateKey(int p, int g) {
    int alicePrivateKey = 12;
    ...
    System.out.println("Alice Private Key: " + alicePrivateKey);
    
    BigInteger gBigInt = BigInteger.valueOf(g).pow(alicePrivateKey);
    BigInteger pBigInt = BigInteger.valueOf(p);
    
    System.out.println("Alice Public Key: " + gBigInt.mod(pBigInt));
    System.out.println();
}

Prime: 941
Base: 627
Alice Private Key: 12
Alice Public Key: 21
```